# How to persist data between CircleCI Jobs using workflows? Specifically gcloud-cli using orbs

Tags: gcloud, circleci, circleci-workflows, gcloud-cli

I'm looking to run a `gcloud` command as part of one of my jobs. Of course, when I initially ran the job I got the error 'command not found'. CircleCI suggests using the `gcloud-cli` orb to install and initialise the gcloud cli.

My workflow looks like this:

```
workflows:
  build and deploy:
    jobs:
      - gcp-cli/install_and_initialize_cli:
          gcloud-service-key: insert_key_as_env_variable
          google-project-id: my_project_id
          google-compute-zone: my_compute_zone
      - build_job:
          requires:
            - gcp-cli/install_and_initialize_cli
```

The `gcp-cli/install_and_initialize_cli` step works perfectly well but when I run the `build_job` it says `gcloud` command not found. I assumed that running the gcp-cli orb would make the gcloud-cli available for all downstream jobs.

Is there a way to make the gcloud-cli available to downstream jobs? I have tried to persist/attach workspaces but with no success (doesn't mean this isn't a possible solution).
The other possible solution is to find a way to run the gcp-cli orb as part of my `build_job`, but I can't quite figure out how to do that either.

For reference my (very stripped down) `build_job`:

```
build_job:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node
    steps:
      - run: gcloud auth configure-docker // FAILS HERE - moved to top on purpose

      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: Install Docker Compose
          command: |
            curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.19.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > ~/docker-compose
            chmod +x ~/docker-compose
            sudo mv ~/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

      - setup_remote_docker

....
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had to work through this myself for a hobby project. I think the `gcp-cli/install_and_initialize_cli` job listed in the orb examples is a red-herring; as you noticed it will run in its own executor and disappear when you hit the next job in the workflow.

An easy way to work around this problem is to a run the [`gcp-cli/install` command](https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/circleci/gcp-cli#commands-install) as a step in your `build_job`. Once you've got the `gcloud` cli installed you can run the appropriate auth and deploy commands. In your case you'd do something like:

```
build_job:
docker:
  - image: circleci/node
steps:
   - gcp-cli/install
   # do gcloud stuff here
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `circleci/node` as a base image in all jobs, and assuming you want `gcloud` to be available in all of them, I would do the following:

Create a new pipeline to build a Docker image, so that when you push to it in version control, it builds the image and pushes the image to a Docker registry. Use `FROM circleci/node` at the start of the `Dockerfile` and then install `gcloud` as you would normally in Linux. Tag it with the URL of your registry, e.g. like `registry.gitlab.com/grant-isdale/gcloud-node`, so that you can push and pull it (substituting your username and registry name as appropriate, of course).

Then, in your CircleCI jobs, use `registry.gitlab.com/grant-isdale/gcloud-node` instead of `circleci/node`. You can add authentication details here if the registry requires authentication.